# Sorting a CSV file, but not it's header

Tags: sort, csv, table, sc-spreadsheet

I need to sort a CSV file, but the the header row (1st row) keeps getting sorted.
This is what I'm using:

```
cat data1.csv | sort -t"|" -k 1 -o data1.csv
```

Here's a sample line:

```
Name|Email|Country|Company|Phone 
Brent Trujillo|tempus@mauris.org|Burkina Faso|Donec LLC|(612) 943-0167
```

Comment: CSV files can have newlines in the individual fields (which need to be quoted), e.g. if you have more details in your addresses or multiple telephone numbers. It is better to be defensive and use real CSV parsing as available in e.g.  Perl and Python for these tasks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should work and output to `data2.csv`:

```
head -n 1 data1.csv > data2.csv &&
tail -n +2 data1.csv | sort -t "|" -k 1 >> data2.csv
```

Comment: Thanks Christopher. It worked! I've been working on this for days now.

Answer (score 1):

I think a big part of the problem here is

```
... -k 1 ...
```

`sort`'s `-k`ey arguments imply *at least* a `-k [num]` *start* **and** `,[num]` *end* reference for each. To say `-k 1` is effectively no different than specifying no sort key at all because without an end reference `sort` will sort lines from the start of the line to its end.

If you wanted to `sort` lines on only the first `|`-delimited field you would need to do:

```
... -k1,1 ...
```

If you did that and if your first line *began* with a `|` then, with GNU `sort` you could just do...

```
sort -st\| -k1,1 <infile >outfile
```

...and the first line would remain as is - you'd get the behavior you desire.

I specify GNU `sort` above because POSIX specifies `sort` to evaluate all bytes on a line *as significant to the comparison* after it has exhausted all sort keys on a non`-u`nique `sort` op *(twice - adjacent equally-keyed lines are specified to at least drop modifiers after the first pass)* and adjacent equally-keyed lines remain. This means that for...

```
printf '|%s\n' 9 1 | sort -nk1,1
```

...a POSIX `sort` prints...

```
|1
|9
```

...which might be counter-intuitive, as the first field - and the only one matched by any `-k` argument - is completely empty. By default GNU `sort` also prints the same , but when the `-s`table sort option is specified it prints...

```
|9
|1
```

...as it does not evaluate any line any further than allowed by the fields specified on the command-line in the same way it would for a `-u`nique sort - though it doesn't remove dups for a `-s`table sort.

Without altering your file at all, if your header line is the first and if you are sorting with a GNU `sort` you can do:

```
{ printf \|; cat file; } | 
sort -st\| -k1,1 | 
sed 's/.//;q'
```

...which, as I think, will get you the results you want on stdout.

Or something like...

```
{ printf \|; cat file; } | 
nl -ba -s\| |
sort -t\| -k2,2 -k1n,1 |
cut -d\| -f2-
```

...for a sure thing with any implementation maybe