# Merging CSV (single line per row) files without losing the header line

Tags: sort, csv-simple

I need to merge two CSV files: `datasorted1.csv` and `datasorted2.csv`, but my headers keep getting sorted.

```
head -n 1 datasorted1.csv datasorted2.csv > resultado.csv && tail -n +2 datasorted1.csv datasorted2.csv | sort -t "|" -k 1 >> resultado.csv
```

Sample data:

```
Name|Email|Country|Company|Phone
Brent Trujillo|tempus@mauris.org|Burkina Faso|Donec LLC|(612) 943-0167
```

Comment: possible double posted question of [Sorting a csv file](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/170600/sorting-a-csv-file)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, read the header from one of the files. Then read the data from both and sort:

```
head -n 1 sample1.csv > results.csv && tail -q -n +2 sample1.csv sample2.csv | sort -t "|" -k 1 >> results.csv
```

Comment: The cmd worked, but now the header is gone. The two headers rows are gone. This is what run: head -n 1 datasorted1.csv && tail -q -n +2 datasorted1.csv datasorted2.csv | sort -t"|" -k 1,1 > resultado.csv

Comment: You're not writing the first 'head' to the file, and your second redirect should append to the file. You should run: head -n 1 datasorted1.csv > resultado.csv && tail -q -n +2 datasorted1.csv datasorted2.csv | sort -t"|" -k 1,1 >> resultado.csv

Comment: Bingo man!!!!!!!!!!!! Thanks for the help, as you can tell I'm a rookie, lol. Thanks Jason.