# Sorting CSV file by first column, ignoring header

Tags: sort, csv

How would I sort a CSV file by the first column, where the first column a lowercase string, ignoring header line?

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/11856/117549

Comment: Also: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/170601/117549

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`sort` does not have an option to exclude header. You can remove the header using:

```
tail -n+2 yourfile | sort
```

This tail syntax gets `yourfile` from second line up to the end of the file.

Of course the results of `sort` will not include the header.

You can isolate the header with command `head -n1 yourfile` which will print only the first line of your file (your header).

To combine them together you can run:

```
head -n1 yourfile && tail -n+2 yourfile | sort
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. Worked a charm. There's a typo on the first line, _yourfile_ and _youfile_, in case someone else wants to use it in the future.

Answer (score 10):

I assume you want to keep the header: redirect the contents of the file into a grouped construct:

```sh
{
    # grab the header and print it untouched
    IFS= read -r header
    echo "$header"
    # now process the rest of the input
    sort
} < file.csv
```

Answer (score 5):

Using  [`csvkit`](http://csvkit.readthedocs.io/):

```
$ csvsort -c 1 file.csv
```

or just

```
$ csvsort file.csv
```

The difference is that the first command will only use the first column, while the second will use all (like `sort` does).

The `csvkit` tools assumes that the input CSV file has a header line as its first line.  Use `-H` if the file has no header.

Comment: Tip: `csvkit` can be installed using Homebrew with `brew install csvkit`. Handy!

Comment: this module can sort the files in place? Thanks

Comment: @PauloSergioSchlogl `csvsort` can not sort files in place. But it's easy to redirect to a temporary file and then replace the original with that.